# Is there a way to check if jQuery has already been attached to an html page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some jQuery which will be put on multiple different HTML pages which I have no clue whether they will have the jQuery Library attached or not. I would like to make it so that it does not load the library if it does already exist on the page so that it can be faster, but I can't figure out if there is a way to check for whether the library already is attached to the page.

Is there a way?

Comment: @Dave: But `$` is used by other things as well, checking `jQuery` is safer.

Comment: The fact that another Dave Newton commented on here a) confused me, then b) blew my mind.

Comment: @newtron What's worse is that my nickname is Newtron/Neutron. Are you me?

Comment: @muistooshort Yep, if OP is mixing libs, sure.

Comment: @Dave Um... maybe I'm you? I'm newtron on Twitter. I think I need a drink.

Comment: @newtron I'll drink to that (`@dave_newton`, though; boring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html):

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Loads a local jQuery file if it hasn't already been loaded.